# truffle migrate command gives Error: Invalid Json Response: ""

Tags: truffle, testrpc, truffle-migration

I've cloned testrpc and have it running in a separate directory.  It's set to the default localhost:8545.  I've successfully installed truffle and ran truffle-init-webpack, then truffle compile.  When I try and migrate my contracts to the testrpc, i get the following error

```
Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: ""
    at Object.InvalidResponse (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v8.1.0\node_modules\truffle\node_modules\web3\lib\web3\errors.js:35:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v8.1.0\node_modules\truffle\node_modules\web3\lib\web3\httpprovider.js:115:32)
    at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v8.1.0\node_modules\truffle\node_modules\xhr2\lib\xhr2.js:64:18)
    at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v8.1.0\node_modules\truffle\node_modules\xhr2\lib\xhr2.js:354:12)
    at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpRequestError (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v8.1.0\node_modules\truffle\node_modules\xhr2\lib\xhr2.js:544:12)
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v8.1.0\node_modules\truffle\node_modules\xhr2\lib\xhr2.js:414:24)
    at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:210:7)
    at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:399:9)
    at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
```

I've checked my truffle.js file and it seems to be correct:

```
require('babel-register')

module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 8545,
      network_id: '*' // Match any network id
    }
  }
}
```

Any idea's why this would be happening would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: I'm on Windows 10, I'm using node 8.1.0 and Truffle 3.2.1

Comment: Is is possible your contract constructor throws for some reason?

Comment: What does testrpc show in its console? Check there is no geth instance running in port 8545.

Comment: @Rob The contracts that I'm using can be found in the repo here:

https://github.com/tomw1808/truffle_eth_class2/tree/master/s06/example_interact_with_contracts_once_deployed/contracts

I checked in the browser IDE and there appears to be no errors being thrown from the constructor.  

Ismael, no instances of geth were running, only the testrpc :-\

Comment: Nothing comes up in the testrpc console...

Comment: Update!  I restarted my machine, ran truffle migrate and it's working now.  Thanks for taking the time to help :-)

Comment: **This error is f___i_g irritating.** Yesterday everything was working fine. Today without changing anything in the project I'm getting this error. :/. Screw this! And yea, **restarting **fixes everything.